# Define a struct pointer as threadprivate in OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, struct, openmp

From C I am calling a piece of Fortran code that then calls some other C code. In order to call the last bit of C code, I need to have two global pointers to an EarthModel struct and a SurveyGeometry struct that I have defined. I have tried to parallelize the for loop below in calcGreen.c, but have been unsuccessful with more than 1 thread (the program segfaults).

I need each thread to have its own pointer to different EarthModels and SurveyGeometrys while keeping the global definition. I tried using the omp threadprivate directive to give each thread its own struct pointer which it can allocate and free and maintain the global definition on the thread level. I have also read that the default stack is 2M for created threads, so I've tried giving the threads more memory by setting the environment variable with export OMP_STACKSIZE=512M (and higher), but the segfault persists.

**shared.h**

```
extern EarthModel *g_em;
extern SurveyGeometry *g_sg;
#pragma omp thradprivate(g_em, g_sg)
```

**util.h**

```
#include "shared.h"

EarthModel *g_em;
SurveyGeometry *g_sg;
```

**calcGreen.c**

```
#include "util.h"

...
omp_set_num_threads(2);
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,1)
for(int ii=0; ii<nseg; ++ii){
  for(int jj=0; jj<nseg; ++jj){
    ...
    // code to allocate and initialize g_sg and g_em
    g_sg = initSG();
    g_em = initEM();
    // code to pass through to Fortran and execute C function on g_sg and g_em
    // code to free g_sg and g_em
    freeSG(g_sg);
    freeEM(g_em);
    ...
  }
}
...
```

EDIT: Alternatively, is there a way of getting the structs g_sg and g_em from the first C function where there are allocated and set to the C function that Fortran calls in a thread safe way without using global variables?

Comment: A couple of comments. The `#pragma omp` you have in shared.h has a typo, it should be `threadprivate` rather than `thradprivate`. Also, since you have a segfault, can you generate a core and show us its content using the backtrace command from gdb?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure why this worked, but spelling "threadprivate" correctly AND moving the #pragma omp threadprivate directive to util.h seems to have done the trick. The first is unsurprising, but the second isn't intuitive to me. Thank you for the help.

Comment: "If a variable is specified in a `threadprivate` directive in one translation unit, *it must be specified in a `threadprivate` directive in every translation unit in which it is declared*." - [OpenMP specification](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-4.5.pdf), Section 2.15.2 (emphasis added)

Answer (score 0):

If Harald's comment does not already solve the problem, some suggestions:

1) If it is allowed to change the source code of calcGreen.c and if each thread does not use the pointers before they are (re-?)allocated and (re-?)initialized by calling initSG() and initEM(), I would declare them as local variables inside the inner for-loop.

2) Are the implementations of initSG(), initEM(), freeSG() and freeEM() thread-safe and reentrant?